# JavaScript ES5 transpile for ES6 const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, polyfills, transpiler

I am writing a transpiled/polyfill code for ES6 'const' to support the old browsers. I extensively searched the net but could not find the exact transpiled code for below:

```
function someFunction () {
   const abc;
}
```

For a global variable, this is possible using Object.defineProperty on window object. But how do I achieve the same on local variables?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I would just use `var` if you really need to support something that old. `const` is a keyword and I don't think those can be 'pollyfilled'. Even if there is a way, I don't think the effort is worth it.

Comment: `const` are replaced with a simple `var`. You can test it via Babel's online compiler with a simple function as https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmYUCW4YF4YAKASgID4YBvAKBhlElgEMCYAGAbhoF8g&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.0&externalPlugins=

Comment: like @Treast said, and if you try modifying the value of a const, Babel will throw an error, similar to how a modern ES6 browser would: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmYUCW4YF4YAKASgID4YBvAKBhlElgEMCYAGAbjplcICZuAXyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.0&externalPlugins=

Comment: Yeah, but Babel will throw the error during compile time, not runtime. If you want to reproduce this behavior on runtime, maybe the `get` / `set` operators can help, but that requires a wrapper for each `const` that you have.

Comment: Hi Treast,  I am also thinking along the lines of get / srt,  can u throw some more light on your view?  Thank ypu.